# Ardour: Setting recording levels

Tags: recording, levels

I'm brand new to Ardour, and not terribly experienced with Linux audio.  My first question about Ardour is probably a very, very, stupid one: why is it that the audiogram of the recording in the track is completely unaffected by any changes I make in the faders?

How can I get the recording levels set correctly if I can't change them?

Answer (score 1):

The track shows the input signal, not the adjustment made by the fader. To adjust this, you have to use the a gain control. There is one in the mixer that might help, but I don't think this will do you much good if the signal coming into Ardour is too high. See the attached screenshot for an example of where to find the controls.

[image: Gain pots are circled; screenshot made by myself.]

If you are recording from eg. a preamp, try to reduce the gain there instead if possible.

Comment: Thank you!  Somehow I missed the gain control when looking at the manual.  Why is the input signal displayed in the audiogram?  Wouldn't the recorded signal be much more useful there?

Comment: The input signal is the same as the recorded signal. The fader controls the output signal. Viewing the input is in some contexts more important than the output from the fader (which can also be seen on the master meter), as this tells you if the preamp is overloaded or the signal is peaking. You usually want a signal as high as possible without peaking, while the position of the fader is more according to taste.